# Accessing a layout during runtime

Tags: qt

I've created some dialog and on this dialog I have a vertical layout consisting of few checkboxes. I'd like to access those checkboxes during runtime via layout containing them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dialog called `myDialog` you can access its layout via

```
myDialog->layout()
```

the layout itself inherits from QObject and like that has access to the [`QObject::children()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qobject.html#children) method.

For example you could do something like this:

```
QCheckBox* currentCheckBox;
foreach( QObject* child, myDialog->layout()->children() )
{
    currentCheckBox = qobject_cast< QCheckBox* >( child );
    if( !currentCheckBox ) continue;

    // do anything with the checkbox here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim: had a similar question and found your answer very helpful.

But at least using PyQt4 I have found that layout itself seems to have no children (`children()` gives an empty list ) -- instead, they are "parented" by the widget that our layout is sitting on.

So in Python, that would be `myDialog.children()` instead of `myDialog.layout().children()`.

And then, obviously, there could be other elements among these children, not necessarily coming from our layout (at least in my case there were).

Moreover, in a more general case, [the order of QObject's children could be unstable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#children) -- though I think for checkboxes it's unlikely to be the case.

So, I have rather used the layout's `.itemAt()` method.

I suppose in C++ it would be something like

```
for( int i=0; ++i; i<layout->count() ) 
{
    widget = layout->itemAt(i)->widget()
    // ... do whatever you want
}
```

In Python, it was

```
for i in xrange( layout.count() ) :  

    widget = layout.itemAt( i ).widget()
    # ... whatever )
```

May be there's something that has changed here between Qt3 and Qt4 ?